# conflict with submit struts 2 and jquery grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts

I'm trying to use a Jquery Grid, in which gridModel is the result of a submit button of struts 2. But the problem is that the submit button didn't work when I add the grid in my jsp.
I whould like to know if submit button have a problem with jquery grid.

This is my jsp:

```
<s:form>
..................
<s:submit name="search" onclick="submitForm()"/>

<s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsontable"/>
<sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="Listes "
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="15"
    rownumbers="true"
>
<sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name"  />
<sjg:gridColumn name="age" index="age" title="Age"/>
<sjg:gridColumn name="adress" index="adress" title="Adress" />
<sjg:gridColumn name="tel" index="tel" title="Tel"   />
</sjg:grid>
</s:form>
```

Comment: can you check with firefox firebug tools if you facing any error or its console showing any error?

Comment: No there is no error on console.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the Struts action you're expecting to call either in the s:form or s:action tags (see http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/submit.html and http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/form.html ).

In the code snippet you show there isn't an action defined. And, unless it's an ajax call, you don't need the onClick attribute (otherwise it would be useful to show us what does the submitForm method do).

Comment: I can't specify my action in s:form because I should test what's the action I will execute, I have 3 different submit button in my jsp.  My js function just submit the button 'document.forms[0].action=action; document.forms[0].submit();'